# solve $k(k-1) \geq \ln2*2m$ for k

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

My Question is related to the birthday problem.

Starting at

$e^{-\frac{k(k-1)}{2m}} \leq 0.5$

i used $ln(x)$ on both sides and multiplied by $-2m$ to get

$k(k-1) \geq \ln2*2m$

According to my book the result (when solving for k) should be

$k \geq \frac{1+\sqrt{1+8m\ln{2}}}{2}$

Can anyone explain how i get there?

Comment: Use the quadratic formula from what you have. (NB: Does anyone have a good duplicate reference for quadratic formula w/ inequality?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can complete the square:
$$
2m\log 2\leq k(k-1)=k^2-2(0.5)k\iff 2m\log2 +\frac{1}{4}\leq(k-0.5)^2
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
k\geq 0.5+\sqrt{2m\log2 +\frac{1}{4}}\quad\text{or}\quad k\leq 0.5-\sqrt{2m\log2 +\frac{1}{4}}.
$$
If you are only interested in positive $k$, then the solution is
$$
k\geq 0.5+\sqrt{2m\log2 +\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{8m\log2+1}}{2}.
$$